# How to get the value in Json where a key has the value in the form of another payload

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I want to get the feed_id (which is 1922 in the given JSON) in the value of key 'payload'

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "is_hide":0,
         "updated_at":"2019-08-02 11:59:50",
         "payload":{
            "action_type":"post_like",
            "sender_name":"Bear Grylls",
            "sender_id":517,
            "sender_thumbnail":"https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/mammalz-qa\/thumbnails\/Abc.",
            "media_type":1,
            "feed_id":1922,
            "message":"Bear Grylls liked your photo."
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Trying to format your input found payload is another JSON, but not parsed - you should parse it first too unless you want to search something in an escaped string...

Answer (score 0):

Try with some way to get feed_id

```
$.data..feed_id

$..feed_id

$.data[0]..feed_id
```